# Java 8 64 bits with jxbrowser process

Tags: jxbrowser

We are using Jxbrowser within java swing.  It is running with Java 8 64 bits.  However, when checking the list of processes in Windows Task Manager - Processes, we see the jxbrowser process is identified as *32 -bits-.

Why using Java 8 64 bits the jxbrowser instanced is for 32 bits?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

JxBrowser 6.21 contains a 32 bit and a 64 bit version. Older versions had only a 32 bit version. So take a look at 6.21.